# Python3 - Download file from google docs private and public url

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-docs, google-docs-api

I want to download files from google docs urls. I want it to know how to authenticate to google to download private files also. I found this [github project](https://github.com/uid/gdoc-downloader) and it is very old, The authentication doesn't work, i can only download public files. Using urllib3 doesn't work and gives me js instead of html.

On the google docs api i've found a code that connects to google and knows only how to get recent docs(of the authenticated user) and things like that.

I need a code (prefer in pyhton3) that knows how to authenticate and download urls straight from google docs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The user has to authenticate the app, which will most likely call a browser which will bring up the user consent screen. You can use the official [Python Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/quickstart/python) to handle this.

As for downloading the docs, the documentation also discusses this ([Download Files](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/manage-downloads)) with some code snippets for python you can use.

Comment: The problem is that oAuth requires human authentication (it opens the browser at the login page). How can i pass it with my crawler?

Comment: I had a guess that you're referring to a headless authentication earlier. From what I read, there's an [old documentation](https://developers.google.com/gdata/articles/using_cURL) in using `curl` to authenticate the user. This might be the nearest thing to what  you want, but may not work for Drive API anymore. If it does work, I believe you can call terminal commands inside python.